# Java calling constructor within another

Tags: java, object, constructor

could someone help me with calling the first constructor and putting it in the second and third? I may have some problems with the syntax, it seems...

http://pastebin.com/5x11Mkyy

Comment: Please post the code directly in your question.

Comment: Please add a concise example of your issue in the body of the question rather than using a pastebin link.

Comment: The syntax for calling one constructor from another (constructor delegation) is indeed different. Use `this(otherargs...)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your linked example is really long and I'm getting confused by all the non-English comments, so I'll just give you a short example. If you want to call another constructor within a constructor, you just use the `this` keyword. Here's a sample class that uses `this` to delegate the work of the "default" (no-arg) constructor to a 1-arg constructor:

```
public class MyClass {

  public final int X;

  public MyClass() {
    this(1); // Use X=1 by default
  }

  public MyClass(int x) {
    X = x;
  }

}
```

This technique is covered in [Using the `this` Keyword: Using `this` with a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies for the foreign comment and lengthy paste.
I've edited the commentary and put up a new link.